# application/soap+msbin1 where is the standard

Tags: soap

I'm working in an environment+language without good library support, and I need to digest xml coming in that's `application/soap+msbin1`. At first I thought it complied to these standards:

```
[MC-NBFX]
[MC-NBFS]
[MC-NBFSE]
```

But I don't believe that it does because it doesn't seem to follow the multiByte31 standard, as well as a few other key pieces. Notably:

```
52 10 02 20 1C 98 2C 75 75 69 64 2D stuff
```

Should correspond to

```
<o:UsernameToken u:ID="uuid-stuff">
```

Except `10 02` in no way can correspond to `0x150` that `UsernameToken` matches according to `[MC-NBFS]`. Any suggestions as to what `msbin1` actually means?